# What is the difference between excitation table and truth table?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

In flip-flops what is truth and excitation table iam getting confused between them ,earlier I learnt a truth table of flip-flops but now its called excitation table so I wanna know whole thing behind this in detail ,what's the difference between truth table and excitation table and how are truth table and excitation table for a flip-flops are constructed.Detailed answer will be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Truth table shows the corresponding outputs for every combination of inputs. 
Consider the truth table of jk flip flop below[image: truth table]

Q(t+1) is new output
Q(t) is present output
Q(t) bar is compliment of present o/p

Now look at excitation table below
[image: excitation table]

Excitation table shows what should be the values of j and k so as to change the present output to the desired value (next output)

Recall 
Q(t+1) is new output
Q(t) is present output

1st combination: present state is 0 and we have to maintain same value to be next state meaning Q(t) and Q(t+1) is 0. Look at truth table. We can "reset" the o/p to 0 or maintain "unchanged" state. That is j and k should have either 1st or 2nd combinations of truth table. (J,k) is (0,0) or (0,1). Means j "must" be 0 and k is dont care (maybe 0 or 1).

2nd combination: present state is 0 and we have to change it to 1. Meaning Q(t) is 0 and Q(t+1) is 1. Look at truth table. We can "set" the o/p to 1 or "toggle" the state from 0 to 1. That is j and k should have either 3rd or 4th combinations of truth table. (J,k) is (1,0) or (1,1). Means j "must" be 1 and k is dont care (maybe 0 or 1).

3rd combination: present state is 1 and we have to change it to 0. Meaning Q(t) is 1 and Q(t+1) is 0. Look at truth table. We can "reset" the o/p to 0 or "toggle" the state from 1 to 0. That is j and k should have either 2nd or 4th combinations of truth table. (J,k) is (0,1) or (1,1). Means j is dont care (maybe 0 or 1) and k "must" be 1.

4th combination: present state is 1 and we have to maintain same value to be next state. Meaning Q(t) and Q(t+1) is 1. Look at truth table. We can "set" the o/p to 1 or maintain "unchanged" state. That is j and k should have either 1st or 3rd combinations of truth table. (J,k) is (0,0) or (1,0). Means j is dont care (maybe 0 or 1) and k "must" be 0.

Hence excitatation table is reverse of the truth table and is applicable only in seqential ciruits where the system remembers what the earlier output is.

Comment: Lol i didn't look the date u asked the question. U would hav figured it out by now

Answer (score 0):

The truth table maps current states and inputs to outputs (on a circuit level).

An excitation table is used when a particular gates needs a particular output in order to implement the truth table.  This is usually done for ***sequential elements*** (latches and flip flops), since the relationships between their inputs and their next state is not always direct.

A D-flip flop has the simplest excitation table (Q = D at the rising edge).  For other sequential elements it is not so straightforward, and the current output state may be needed to properly compute the next state.

For example a T flip flop needs to know the current state to know what the proper input is to cause a '0' at the output.  Also JK and SR latches have slightly more complex excitation tables.